Axler Theorem 5.17, part (b)
I am trying to understand the proof of part (b) of Theorem 5.17 in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. He cites part (a) in his proof of (b), so I've written out the full theorem statement below. $\mathcal{P}(F)$ is his notation for polynomials with coefficients in the field $F$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is his notation for the set of linear operators $V \to V$.

Suppose $p,q \in \mathcal{P}(F)$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Then
a) $(pq)(T) = P(T) q(T)$;
b) $p(T) q(T) = q(T) p(T)$.

I understand his proof of part (a). His proof of part (b) is in one line. He says:

Using (a) twice, we have $p(T) q(T) = (pq)(T) = (qp)(T) = q(T) p(T)$.

The first equality is part (a) and the third equality is (a) with the roles of $p$ and $q$ interchanged. I don't understand the second equality. If $p$ and $q$ were functions from $F$ to $F$, then that $pq = qp$ is true by commutativity of field multiplication. But I don't understand how we can state that $pq = qp$ at the level of operators.

In $\mathcal{P}(F)$, the polynomials $pq$ and $qp$ are equal. They are being viewed as polynomials, not as operators nor as polynomial functions.

@ArturoMagidin I'm a little confused by this. I understand that, in $\mathcal{P}(F)$, $pq = qp$. I understand there's a distinction between polynomials as a symbolic object and polynomial functions, though Axler defines a polynomial as a function. I think the definition of $p(T)$ extends the function to operators.

$f(T)$ is an operator that is defined exclusively in terms of what the polynomial $f(x)$ is. Equal polynomials define equal operators. Since the polynomials $f_1(x)=p(x)q(x)$ and $f_2(x)=q(x)p(x)$ are the same polynomial, it follows that the operator $f_1(T)$ is the same operator as $f_2(T)$... because they are defined by the same polynomial.

Thank you. This makes sense.

(Aside: in general it is important to keep straight the distinction between polynomials and polynomial functions. Every polynomial defines a polynomial function, but in general different polynomials may define the same functiob. For the reals and the complex numbers this does not happen, and the image of the polynomial ring in the ring of functions $F\to F$ is isomorphic to the ring of polynomials. But this need not happen in general. For polynomials over a field, it happens if and only if the field is infinite. Axler is eliding the distinction to simplify things. I do not)

Also note that as polynomial functions defined on $\mathcal{L}(V), pq$ and $qp$ are still equal, because while multiplication (aka, composition) of linear operators is not commutative in general, the operators that are being multiplied are all powers of the same operator $T$, and all these do commute with each other. Thus the same proof that shows $pq = qp$ as polynomial functions on the field, also shows that $(pq)(T) = (qp)(T)$ for each linear operator $T$.
